# Issue with GET forms and Node.JS and Express

Tags: forms, node.js, get, express

I've hot a very simple form in HTML, that sends GET information to my Node.JS server, with Express. This is the form:

```
    <form method="get" action="/search" autocomplete="off" class="navbar-search pull-left">
       <input name="search" type="text" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Search..." />
    </form>
```

And this is the server part:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res){

   console.log(req.query["search"]);

   res.render('search.ejs')

});
```

When I write something to the input, and press enter, and the page keeps loading for a long while, and I receive a 340 error when I get in for example in `http://localhost:8080/search?search=foo`. I think I have a problem with the from, that doesn't send properly the values, because it doesn't work with `POST`request too. Any solution for this?

Thank's advance!

Comment: Does your console.log() statement execute? ie, can you see the req.query['search'] value in your server logs?

Comment: No, I don't get anything in the console

Comment: I feel that the answer provided to you below is probably correct. However if I were testing this the first thing I would do would be to ensure that my request is actually reaching the route, which I would do by adding in a static statement; something like "console.log('here')". As well, if your request is hitting the correct route and your response is hanging you likely have some errors that were printed in your logs. I would check those.

Comment: Do you mean a 304 error, instead of 340? That would mean some part of your application thinks the request isn't going to produce a different response from a previously (cached by your browser) response. If so, please post more of your application's code.

Comment: Now I get error 324, `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have to use the req.params.search instead of req.query which does not work.

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res){
   var search = req.query.search;

   console.log(search);

   res.render('search.ejs')

});
```

Here you can read more about it:
http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param

Comment: `params` are the parameters set by placeholders in your route (`/search/:key` would create `req.params.key`). The proper way to access parameters passed in a querystring is indeed via `req.query`, or possible via `req.param(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Next time to figure out an erorr, type in `app.get(...  console.log(res, req);` and find where your variables are.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting, for me it worked!

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res){
   var search = req.query;

   console.log(search, 'of type', typeof search);
   res.send("the query is about the student with name " + search.sname + ' and subject '+search.ssubject );

});
```

with the form

```
<form method= 'GET' action="/search" autocomplete="off">
            Student Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="sname">
            <br>
            Student Subject:<br>
            <input type="text" name="ssubject">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
```